# Switch perspective in a RCP application since Eclipse Juno?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-indigo, eclipse-juno

In my RCP application I use this code to switch perspective :

```
IWorkbenchWindow window = getViewSite().getWorkbenchWindow();
window.getWorkbench().showPerspective(PRODUCT_PERSPECTIVE_ID, window);
```

I didn't change my code but I changed my developement environnement from

```
java 6 64bits + windows + Eclipse Indigo
```

to

```
java 7 32bits + windows + Eclipse Juno
```

And now the perspective doesn't switch any more, with no exception and nothing suspect visible in debug.

I didn't find any bug report.

Is there an explanation ? A workaround ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have run into this problem as well.  As far as I can tell, it is a regression in Juno (4.2.0).  I used the debugger to step through the call to *showPerspective()*.  At no point was any explicit attempt made to actually change the perspective.  Perhaps there is an internal event listener missing, or perhaps the port of *showPerspective()* to the new framework is incomplete.

As a work-around, the following code successfully changed perspectives for me:

```
IWorkbenchWindow window = getViewSite().getWorkbenchWindow();
IPerspectiveRegistry registry = workbench.getPerspectiveRegistry();
IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();
page.setPerspective(registry.findPerspectiveWithId(PRODUCT_PERSPECTIVE_ID));
```

Depending upon the context in which these calls are made, you might want to null-guard some of these calls, or check `Workbench.isClosing()` to be safe.

Comment: Thanks. That's not the solution I choose for my program, I did what's written in my answer as Juno is much too buggy and ugly to enter production today. But your answer seems good and might be useful to others so I finally accept it :)

Comment: @dystroy Thanks for the accept.  I have come to the same conclusion as you: the 4.x versions are still too buggy.

Answer (score 2):

This is bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=395084 and fixed for Eclipse Luna which is scheduled to be released in June.

Comment: No problem at all. I am actually using the workaround provided here because Luna isn't officially released yet and using it gives other bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer that aims at clarifying and solving my problem :

Using the Eclipse 4 IDE, build a RCP application developped before Eclipse 4, integrating Java 7 features and compatible with Windows 32 bits. And of course be able to switch perspective.

This answer doesn't solve the problem of those who'd want to switch perspective in a RCP application AND use the features or look of the new Eclipse 4 Platform (not to be confused with the Eclipse 4 IDE). But I wouldn't recommend it, at least for an old application (that is developped on Eclipse 3), given that :

- that's so slow it renders the application barely usable
- there are numerous graphical glitches
- there are bugs, among them the one related to perspective switch

For these 3 points, I can't say if it's due to the Eclipse 4 platform or the Eclipse 3 compatibility layer. I hope new applications developed specifically for the new Eclipse 4 platform would correctly run.

**So my solution was to define an Eclipse 3 target and use it for the build.**

Here's the complete procedure :

1. Have the JDK 7 installed (32bits version)
2. Install Eclipse 3.7 (32bits version)
3. Install Eclipse 4 (32bits version)
4. Launch Eclipse 4 and import the needed projects
5. Go to Window/Preferences/Plug-in Development/Target Platform
6. Click "Add" then "Nothing"
7. Click "Add" then "Installation" and choose your Eclipse 3.7 directory
8. Once your target created, select it (still in Window/Preferences/Plug-in Development/Target Platform)

Now, in your `.product`, the "Eclipse Product Export Wizard" will build an Eclipse 3 executable.

Practical notes :

- "clean all" wasn't enough and I had to stop/restart Eclipse to get it working after target selection
- the installation process erased some on my `.product` fields. I had to reset the ID and to check "The product includes native laucher artifacts"